# How to take the determinant of a rank(1,1) tensor?

Tags: determinant, tensors, calculus-of-variations, symmetry, jacobian

I want to find the Jacobian matrix and its determinant of the generic infinitesimal transformation:

$x'^\mu=x^\mu+\epsilon_\alpha\frac{\delta x^\mu}{\delta \epsilon_\alpha}$ where $\epsilon_\alpha$ is small and might be dependant on $x$.

I think the Jacobian matrix is

$\partial_\nu x'^\mu=\delta^\mu_\nu+\frac{\delta x^\mu}{\delta \epsilon_\alpha}\partial_\nu\epsilon_\alpha+\epsilon_\alpha\partial_\nu\frac{\delta x^\mu}{\delta \epsilon_\alpha}$ where $\partial_\nu=\frac{\partial}{\partial x^\nu}$

where I suspect the last term to be zero since $\partial_\nu\frac{\delta x^\mu}{\delta \epsilon_\alpha}=\frac{\delta \partial_\nu x^\mu}{\delta \epsilon_\alpha}=\frac{\delta \delta^\mu_\nu}{\delta \epsilon_\alpha}=0$ in other words I suspect the derivative to commute with the functional derivative. So we get:

$\partial_\nu x'^\mu=\delta^\mu_\nu+\frac{\delta x^\mu}{\delta \epsilon_\alpha}\partial_\nu\epsilon_\alpha$.

Now I want to know the determinant of this expression but am not totally sure how to go about getting this properly.

The reason that I want this is to derive a general expression for the conserved current that I had previously not encountered:

$j_\alpha^\mu=\Big[\frac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial(\partial_\mu \Phi)}\partial_\nu \Phi-\delta^\mu_\nu\mathcal{L}\Big]\frac{\delta x^\nu}{\delta \epsilon_\alpha}-\frac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial(\partial_\mu \Phi)}\frac{\delta F}{\delta \epsilon_\alpha}$ where $F=\Phi'(x')$

This is encountered in the lecture notes of Joshua D. Qualls called "[Lectures on Conformal Field Theory](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1511.04074.pdf)". The expression is given on p.35. There is an exercise on p.162 that is supposed to guide you through the derivation.